# Facebook Graph API POST picture in a specific app album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Facebook App that POST a picture to a specific album created also by my app. If I run the app the second time it will create another album and POST the new picture there. I would like if the user POST a new one, the picture to be placed in the same album and if is not there to be created. Here is my code so far:

```
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?" . "access_token=". $access_token;
$album_name = 'MyApp Album';
$album_description = 'Album description';
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array('name'=> $album_name,
      'message'=> $album_description
          ));
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'=> 'POST',
    'header'=> 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $postdata
    ));
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, false, $context));
$album_id = $result->id;
$file = $_POST['photo'];
$args = array(
    'message' => 'Photo from application',
    );
$args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$album_id."/photos?access_token=" . $access_token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(json_decode($data,true));
```

I don't wanna use FQL queries if isn't absolutely neccesary. If I can search probably for the album name and then return the ID it would be great.

Comment: a) what have you tried, and b) why are you doing that stuff manually instead of using the PHP SDK (which you tagged this question with, but are not actually using anywhere)?

Comment: I've tried using FQL queries to retrieve the album ID based on the album name: "MyApp Album" and if there is no album named like this move on to create a new one but i prefer not using fql queries but I don't know another aproach. b) it was working for me just with curl, probably I didn't use it like it should?